# ELB AWS response slower than Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

Hey so we are currently running our production environment on Rackspace and are planning to migrate over to AWS.

On rackspace we have

server 1 (nginx as reverse proxy) --> server 2, server 3 and server 4

On AWS we have:

ELB -> server 1 (nginx) --> server 2, server 3 and server 4

Now the speed at which plain js files are downloaded is 2 or 3 times slower on AWS. Is it possible the ELB config is causing this? Is there a way to increase the bandwidth? Or should we use ELB as a reverse proxy?

Comment: Are you doing a stress test?? ELB is elastic, it will increase/decrease capacity as you use it, a light or never used ELB will be slower on heavy or peak traffics

Comment: You should look at Application Load Balancer if you are referring to ELB Classic.  What's your definition of "slower?"  Time to first byte?  What kind of numbers do you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar setup, and have no issues with latency. A cold ELB will run slow, so if its a new setup, then you will get more latency.

Regarding the proxy behind the ELB on AWS. I would remove that.  The ELB needs to register/listen to each individual server, so that autoscaling works.  If you only connect ELB<=>proxy, then the ELB will not scale correctly, as it does not know the health status of the servers in the cluster.

Comment: *"I would remove that."*  ELB scales on traffic, not instance health.  I routinely run proxies between ELB and application servers.  There are a number of solid reasons to design this way, although ALB provides some features that make this less necessary.  In any event, it should not explain any performance discrepancy compared to the stack on Rackspace.